# Windows UWP, application crashing while suspending during async call

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-10-universal

In my Windows store application, I have a await function, which sometimes takes couple of minutes to complete (will consult about performance in some other thread). Meanwhile if a user focuses out of the application, it crashes. When I checked event log, I got following error:

> App was terminated because it took too long to suspend.

I am using Prism in the application. I have handled `Application.Current.Suspending`, with following code (which is always called):

```
    protected void OnApplicationSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
    {
        var defferal = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
        if (sessionStateService.SessionState.ContainsKey("plotId"))
        {
            sessionStateService.SessionState.Remove("plotId");
        }

        sessionStateService.SessionState.Add("plotId", Plot.Id);

        if (sessionStateService.SessionState.ContainsKey("Page"))
        {
            sessionStateService.SessionState.Remove("Page");
        }

        sessionStateService.SessionState.Add("Page", "OperationRecording");

        defferal.Complete();
    }
```

I have also overridden OnNavigatingFrom function, for saving the navigation parameter (and it does nothing else).

```
    public override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingFromEventArgs e, Dictionary<string, object> viewModelState, bool suspending)
    {
        if (viewModelState.ContainsKey("plotId"))
        {
            viewModelState.Remove("plotId");
        }

        viewModelState.Add("plotId", Plot.Id);

        base.OnNavigatingFrom(e, viewModelState, suspending);
    }
```

I am not able to figure out how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 4):

If you suspend your app you should complete it in 5 seconds.
Read [Application.Suspending](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br242341)

> Saving data prior to suspension is useful because the Suspending event
>   handler has only 5 seconds to complete its operation.

So, better save large amount of data due application working.
You can also read [Guidelines for app suspend and resume](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465088.aspx)

In UWP you can also make suspended time larger with help of Extended Execution